# How to filter second parameter based on first parameter using MDX?

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, mdx

I am new to MDX and am trying to write some custom code to get the parameter drop downs in my SSRS report to be the way they are required.

I wrote one query that works and it feeds the data for a parameter I have. This is confirmed working. Now that I have that parameter, I want to write another query for another parameter, where I will use the values from the first parameter to filter the second. So when the user chooses one or more of the options from the drop down, then the result of the second parameter will be filtered based on the user selection.

I've written the following code and I cannot see why it is not working.

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[ParameterValue] AS 
      [Agent].[Department].CURRENTMEMBER.UNIQUENAME 
SELECT 
{
      [Measures].[ParameterValue]
} ON COLUMNS, 
Descendants
(
      [Agent].[Department].[Enterprise Group]
)
ON ROWS 
FROM 
( 
      SELECT 
      ( 
            STRTOSET(@BU, CONSTRAINED) 
      ) ON COLUMNS 
FROM [State Perspective]
)
```

@BU is my first parameter. I would expect the query to filter based on it but it does not.

When I first tried to close Query Designer I got the following error:

> The Query contains the BU parameter, which is not declared.

So I right-clicked the data grid area and set up the parameter and value point to some example data in the cube. This fixed that issue and I was able to click OK on the Query Designer.

But the query does not filter as needed. Instead all results are returned instead of filtered values.

What am I doing wrong here, or can this even be done, to filter another parameter based on the values in a previous parameter?

I've done this in regular SQL with SSRS and it works just fine. But how is it done with a Cube and MDX?

Comment: what is the value of @BU ?

Comment: @whytheq the value of BU is a string such as "Word" or "Apple". It comes from a previous parameter that the user selects.

Comment: then it needs to be the complete string for a set which SSAS will recognize as a set, such as `"{[Fruit].[type].[" + @BU + "]}"`.

Answer (score 0):

The following is direct from this MSDN forum post: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sqlserver/en-US/1f7e872a-d75f-440a-8ab8-88694e6c5370/error-while-passing-parameter-to-mdx-query-on-ssrs

> Hi Srini... are you using the SSAS query designer in BIDS in text
>   mode?  If so, you need to explicitly declare your parameters in the
>   query designer as described [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159254(SQL.90).aspx), in the section on "Using Query
>   Parameters".

---

Edit

Here is the documentation for the `strToSet` function: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144782.aspx

If @BU is say "Apple" the you need to do something like this:

```
strToSet('{[Fruit].[type].[' + @BU + ']}', constrained)
```